# I can't deploy Springboot on Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

When I'm trying to deploy springboot application on heroku i have this error :

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project backend: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]

Comment: Looks like compilation error and not deployment error. Can you update the question with pom.xml and command you are using to compile/build?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be platform is not supporting Java 11. Can you try with Maven Compiler version with some lower version like 8.